# To get a parameter value which is passed inside a URL to a variable in a servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I want to get a parameter value which is passed inside a URL to a variable in a servlet.

I wrote the service as below.

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{name}")
    public Response getUserDetails(@PathParam("name") String email){
        String output = "User info ..  "+name ;
       // String queryParamStr = request.getQueryString();
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    } 
}
```

I used below URL to test the service.
...//localhost:8080/Jersey-Rest/rest/hello/hansi

It shows the output as User info ..hansi

now I want to pass this parameter value to a servlet. I wrote a servlet as below.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {

        String parameter=request.getParameter("name");
        System.out.println("##########parameter############"+parameter);

    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Below is my web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.mkyong.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I want to get the value "hansi" to the parameter variable. But I can't get. I am very new to java web.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `request.getRequestUri()`

If you call the servlet with `localhost:8080/Jersey-Rest/rest/hello/hansi`, getRequestUri will return `/Jersey-Rest/rest/hello/hansi`. Then you can retrieve the 'hansi' from this string.

Example code:

```
String uri = request.getRequestUri();
String[] params = uri.Split("/");
String name = params[params.length()-1];

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println( "Name : " + name);
```

Comment: Right  ... You can also use request.getPathInfo()